# What does "be the inclusion" mean?

Tags: definition

Can anyone explain what the phrase means? To be specific, my notes has the phrase "let $f:A \rightarrow B $ be the inclusion". Does this mean the identity map?

Comment: According to one fastidious usage, "$x$ contains $y$" means $y\in x$ but "$x$ includes $y$" means $y\subset x$.  That makes sense because people say "partially ordered by inclusion" but never (as far as I know, but what do I know?) "partially ordered by containment".  But that fastidious usage fails to be universally or even very widely adhered to by mathematicians, _except_ in some contexts like that of your question or the "partially ordered" locution.  At any rate, they're saying $B$ includes $A$, i.e. $A\subseteq B$, and $f(a)=a$ for $a\in A$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/24499-be-the-change-that-you-wish-to-see-in-the

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that $A\subseteq B$ and that $f(a)=a$ for every $a$ in $A$. But $f$ is not the identity map unless $B=A$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining!